# XSL merge two xml files and update both

Tags: xslt, merge

I have two similar named xml files. One is in local directory and one is on url.
I need a process that merge these two files and update both the local and the external files to the merged version.
The reason for this is that we are about 10 users that want to contribute to make the "database" bigger and take advantage of the entries our friends make.
We run the same software (flight sim) and when we store routes, they are stored locally in companyroutes.xmlin the directory c:/prosim737/. This is the same for all users.
Our external file is placed on our server: www.ourserver.org/cr/companyroutes_net.xml. Name on the external file have been changed, added _net, to keep names appart in my testscripts.

You helped med with a xsl file that translate this file into a html table the other day. This way we are able to see wich routes are stored at any given time, in list form. very usefull.

Now I need help to make a automatic process to merge and update BOTH files, local and external.

Example xml external file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cr.xsl"?>
    <companyroutes>
      <route name="ENBRENGM">ENBR GITRO L24 ADOPI ENGM</route>
      <route name="ENGMENKB">ENGM EVTOG L997 OSVIG P615 INLAS ENKB</route>
      <route name="ENGMENBR">ENGM ATLAP N623 PIRAG ENBR</route>
      <route name="EHAMEGLL">EHAM GORLO L980 LOGAN EGLL</route>
    </companyroutes>
```

Example xml local file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companyroutes>
  <route name="ENGMEKCH">ENGM OKSAT L996 SVD EKCH</route>
  <route name="ENVAENBR">ENVA GEVLI Z108 ROXET ENBR</route>
  <route name="EKCHENGM">EKCH VEDAR L997 LUNIP ENGM</route>
  <route name="EKCHEHAM">EKCH LANGO P999 EEL UP603 BEDUM EHAM</route>
  </companyroutes>
```

Example result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<companyroutes>
  <route name="ENGMEKCH">ENGM OKSAT L996 SVD EKCH</route>
  <route name="ENVAENBR">ENVA GEVLI Z108 ROXET ENBR</route>
  <route name="EKCHENGM">EKCH VEDAR L997 LUNIP ENGM</route>
  <route name="EKCHEHAM">EKCH LANGO P999 EEL UP603 BEDUM EHAM</route>
  <route name="ENBRENGM">ENBR GITRO L24 ADOPI ENGM</route>
  <route name="ENGMENKB">ENGM EVTOG L997 OSVIG P615 INLAS ENKB</route>
  <route name="ENGMENBR">ENGM ATLAP N623 PIRAG ENBR</route>
  <route name="EHAMEGLL">EHAM GORLO L980 LOGAN EGLL</route>
  </companyroutes>
```

and for the external copy:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="cr.xsl"?>
    <companyroutes>
      <route name="ENGMEKCH">ENGM OKSAT L996 SVD EKCH</route>
      <route name="ENVAENBR">ENVA GEVLI Z108 ROXET ENBR</route>
      <route name="EKCHENGM">EKCH VEDAR L997 LUNIP ENGM</route>
      <route name="EKCHEHAM">EKCH LANGO P999 EEL UP603 BEDUM EHAM</route>
      <route name="ENBRENGM">ENBR GITRO L24 ADOPI ENGM</route>
      <route name="ENGMENKB">ENGM EVTOG L997 OSVIG P615 INLAS ENKB</route>
      <route name="ENGMENBR">ENGM ATLAP N623 PIRAG ENBR</route>
      <route name="EHAMEGLL">EHAM GORLO L980 LOGAN EGLL</route>
      </companyroutes>
```

Any help much apprechiated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not show any effort to solve the problem yourself, I'll only give you a hint.

This can be done with the `document()` function of XSLT. For example, retrieve content from the XML file "external.xml" like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('external.xml')/companyroutes/route[@name='ENGMEKCH']"/>
```